# nucleolus of a game

Tags: game-theory

I would like to understand in the snippet below in the definition $2.1$, what does it mean
for a game $(N,v)$ to **have a nucleolus**. And also what does $IG$ stand for.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A game has a nucleolus whenever it is essential (Def.2.1), that is to say that the game has a non-empty imputation set. If it is inessential (reverse of Def. 2.1), then the imputation set is empty, and the nucleolus does not exist, since it is a point in the imputation set that satisfies accentuated geometric properties (cf. Maschler,Peleg and Shapley (1979), Geometric Properties of the Kernel, Nucleolus and Related Solution Concepts, Mathematics of Operations Research, pp.303-338).